# Fetch updated Application Context when opening WatchOS2

Tags: ios, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

So I've went through a lot of tutorials on WatchOS2.

1. I can increase , decrease counters (label value) from both iPhone simulator and iWatch simulator(while both is active).
2. When iOS app is inactive(terminated), watchOS2 app is active, changing value in watchOS2 app, then opening iOS app, counter label is changing.

But the reverse is not working. Changing the label counter in iOS application while watchOS2 app is inactive(terminated). Then opening watchOS2 app but the value is unchanged or NOT the same as the iOS app.

For changing values I used this method

```
   NSDictionary *dic = @{@"counter":[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.counter]};
   WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
   NSError *error;
  [session updateApplicationContext:dic error:&error];
```

I used [this](http://kristina.io/watchos-2-tutorial-using-application-context-to-transfer-data-watch-connectivity-2/) tutorial, and according to this tutorial `[session updateApplicationContext:dic error:&error];` is a method where the whole context is updated or changed. So when a watchOS2 application is getting active, shoudn't it fetch the latest context which was updated by the iOS application while the watchOS2 app was terminated.

Please suggest what i have to do. I am not finding a single solution or all tutorial found, does'nt solve this issue.

Comment: From the discussion to my answer: your question does not describe exactly what you experience. please show the code that is responsible for receiving, including how you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have two application contexts: one that goes from iOS to watch os and one vice versa. Don't think of them as one.

you might consider the following idea:

use only the context from the iOS app to the watch(es).

1. iOS holds the state, sends updates of the state as context to the watch as you did before.
2. if necessary, send differences via the user info queue from watchOS to iOS. A user info message should contain something like "add 1 to counter". user info does not get lost, it is queued if not deliverable at the moment.
3. when the iOS app receives an "add 1 to counter", it does that, updates its UI and also sends the final result as context to the watches.

This should also work when a user has two watches.

Comment: I know that both are separate contexts. but all we can do is update the context while receiving change notification. How can i pass iOS context to the watch

Comment: Did not send a context from watch to iOS because it doesn't make sense in my cases for similar reasons than in your case. What I did and what works is sending user info from watch to iOS with update info as I described. You might add a timestamp or a version number to your context. Then you send the user info "add 1 to counter of version xxx"

Comment: that wont work, what about sending strings. 
What if we set some value in the iOS app, while the watch app is terminated/inactive. Then after i open watchapp, i wont be able to get the updated data? If the app dsnt have any server.

Comment: Why won't that work? I did not say anything about the data format you use to transfer the information.  You use Strings or whatever works for you. Your scenario works fine if you continue sending context from your iOS app to your watch app as suggested.

Comment: I am sending context from iOS app to watchOS and vice versa.. 
It is working when iOS app is inactive and watchOS is updating context, the updated value is being retrieved from iOS app.
But when iOS app is updating context and watchOS app is inactive, when watchOS app is again being active, the changes or new context is not being received.

Comment: Not received by the watch app? Then your mistake might be that you're only waiting for a callback in your watch app. You have to do both in your watch app: reading the context from the session at startup time *and* waiting for callbacks with the updated context.

Comment: I am doing that.. the receive delegate is there in both the watchOS interface n the iOS viewcontroller.
Contexts are being recieved when both apps are active and with correct value. Contexts is being recieved by iOS app when watchApp is active and iOS app is inactive with updated value. When watchOS app is inactive and we change value in iOS app. then in watchOS app willActivate will start but calling `applicationContext` gives the previous context, hence that means context was not updated.

Comment: According to Apple you should never implement the receiver in the watchOS interface or in the iOS ViewController. Use your AppDelegate / ExtensionDelegate to receive session callbacks.

Comment: sounds worthy of a bug report with apple then